# Subring Isomorphism Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having difficulty on where to start with this problem, so any insight would be much appreciated.

If we let R be a ring and A,B be ideals of R, how could it be proved that R/A ∩ B is isomorphic to some subring of R/A x R/B?

The hint was given to define θ:R → R/A×R/B by θ(r) = (A+r, B+r).

Comment: what is the kernel of $\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your notes, there must be:

> **Proposition.** If $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$, then there exists a unique ring structure on $R/I$ such that the canonical surjection $\pi:R\twoheadrightarrow R∕I$ is a ring homomorphism. Furthermore, if $f:R\rightarrow R'$ is a ring homomorphism such that $I\subseteq\ker(f)$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\overline{f}:R/I\rightarrow R'$ such that $f=\overline{f}\circ\pi$ and if $I=\ker(f)$, then $\overline{f}$ is injective.

**Hint.** What is the kernel of $\theta$?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the hint. I claim that $\ker(\theta) = A \cap B$.

Suppose $x \in A \cap B$. Then $\theta(x) = (x + A, x + B) = (0 + A, 0 + B)$ since $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. So $x \in \ker(\theta)$.

Now suppose $x \in \ker(\theta)$. Then $(x + A, x + B) = \theta(x) = (0 + A, 0 + B)$. So $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Thus $x \in A \cap B$.

By the first isomorphism theorem, $$ \frac{R}{A\cap B} = \frac{R}{\ker{\theta}} \cong \text{image}(\theta) \subseteq \frac{R}{A} \times \frac{R}{B}_.$$